# framework to be used for UI of node.js backend

Tags: html, node.js

I am trying to develop an application using node.js.

Since the same application can be accessed from a mobile device sometime later, it is expected that the APIs will return the json data, and not forward the request to a page after setting the appropriate request parameters.

I am mostly a Java backend guy and a newbie in the UI frameworks(including javascript with just basic knowledge).

I was wondering which UI technologies should i use for the UI? Should i go for plain HTML or php or anything else? Also, will the other UI Application be a webapp and deployed probably in a web server?

Started to use the express module for node.js, and it is awesome. It provides jade(and from which the basic UI can be created very easily) but i have not had the chance to see much into it. Also if i start to use jade, i guess in my app.js file, i will need to forward the request to a page, and not return json data, which i want to avoid.

Can someone suggest me which UI technologies should be the way to go?

The UI is supposed to be quite rich, and with lots of functionalities.

Thanks

Tuco

Comment: well Backbone.js is designed with a restful application in mind, mix it with jQuery for binding backbone together with the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using [express.js](http://expressjs.com/). As you mentioned you can render jade templates and this will display to the user as html.

You can also send plane old JSON data to the client by using the [`res.json()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json) method made available with express.

[Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) is a client side framework where you can make single page web applications, and all the html templates are rendered on the clients machine rather than on the web server. Data is persisted to a backend database by using a RESTful API and the following ajax requests. GET, POST, PUT and DELETE.

Later down the line you can use this RESTful API for your mobile app.